# equivalent of copy command to init the database via entry point

Tags: docker, docker-compose

What is the equivalent of specifying the schema of a database in docker-compose.yml file.

**database/Dockerfile**

```
FROM mysql:5.7

COPY ./schema.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  database:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    container_name: "mysql"
    ports:
      - "6603:3306"
```

---

**Attempts**

I've attempted with the following. Is it possible?

```
version: '3'

services:
  database:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    container_name: "mysql"
    ports:
      - "6603:3306"
    command: --init-file /database/schema.sql
      volumes:
        - ./init.sql:/database/schema.sql
```

Comment: Yes? Does docker compose complains? There doesn't appear to have anything too wrong here, except your indention, which I don't know if it's a copy issue or you did errored here.

Comment: indentation is right since I'm using an IDE, it's just that I'm not familiar with this command, i copied pasted, I don't have init.sql, I only have database/schema.sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have `schema.sql` somewhere on your host filesystem, let's assume it's on `./database/schema.sql`. Then you should have such a compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  database:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    container_name: "mysql"
    ports:
    - "6603:3306"
    volumes:
    - ./database/schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

This image does not support any `--init-file` command. Instead, it accepts init scripts put under directory `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`.